# slider does not move when browser is headless

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

When chrome is in headless mode, slider does not move to right. I have tried all this but no success. please let me know what else can be done?

```
<div class="noUi-handle noUi-handle-lower" data-handle="0" tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-orientation="horizontal" aria-valuemin="0.0" aria-valuemax="100.0" aria-valuenow="0.0" aria-valuetext="0.00"><div class="noUi-tooltip">undefined</div></div>


@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[@role='slider']")
public WebElement someslider;

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);

        action.dragAndDropBy(someslider, 200, 100).perform();

        action.clickAndHold(someslider).moveByOffset(200,100).release(someslider).release().build().perform();

        int x=10;
       int width=someslider.getSize().getWidth();
        action.dragAndDropBy(someslider, ((width*x)/100), 0);
        action.build().perform();

          action.clickAndHold().dragAndDropBy(someslider, 200, 100).build().perform();
```

also tried

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('noUi-handle noUi-handle-lower').setAttribute('aria-valuetext', '5.00')");
```

My browser config

```
        if (Hooks.environmentConfigurations.isHeadlessMode()) {
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless", "window-size=1400,600");
            chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        }
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't move? Obviously, you cannot see it in headless mode. What is the outcome of your script? Any messages or notifications?

Comment: So next step after the slider movement is to action on the element thats displayed on moving the slider and that fails and screenshot is captured. Screenshot shows that slider has not moved and element to be actioned has not been displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the window size to window-size=1600,800 and it worked